# WkHTMLtoPDF output as string in order to send as an attachment

Tags: php, formatting, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to use a function, much like mPDF's Output("", "S") format to send WkHTMLtoPDF data so that it can be processed like this:

```
  $attachments = array(
      'filecontent' => $pdf,
      'filename' => $title . '.pdf',
      'filemime' => 'application/pdf',
    );
```

My first guess would be to return the send() function in WkHTMLtoPDF's PHP wrapper, but this does not appear to work - so I'm somewhat lost about how to get the correct type of formatting for the data I have. It appears to need to pass a PDF as string data, which doesn't exactly make sense to me, as I would think PDF data needs to be passed at binary code.

If anyone can elaborate or give me some information about how to pass information correctly, that'd be great.

Comment: Basically, I want to convert an object to a string.

Comment: The send() function outputs the headers so definitely won't return it as a string.

Have you tried the saveAs() function? You might have to save the contents to a file first, and then read the contents of the file. It's been a while since I worked with WkHtmlToPdf so I might be wrong.